# Retrieve the last entry in the user table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the `id` of two users to insert them into the `from_user_id` and `to_user_id` columns of a table.

This is what I tried:

```
INSERT INTO message(from_user_id, to_user_id, text, created_at)
SELECT user.id, user.id, "selam", created_at 
FROM user WHERE username = "admin"
FROM user WHERE username = "user_id"
```

How do I select the last user in the user table as the recipient?

Comment: You have a column with date "created at". Is this the date of the last entry in table users ?

Comment: Yeah. records the last time he entered the site.

Comment: What database do you use ? Oracle, SQLServer, MySQL...

Comment: Mysql I use....

Comment: Is the column id in the table user, added automatically? does the last user entered in that table has the largest id ?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for a trigger that fires every time you insert a row in user and creates an according entry in message. You would access the user ID with new.user_id inside the trigger.

Comment: On a side note: Although MySQL allows you to use double quotes for string literals, you do so. The standard delimiter for string literals is the single quote. Hence: `WHERE username = 'admin'` etc.

Answer (score 0):

SQL

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM user ORDER BY to_user_id DESC

MySql

SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY to_user_id DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: Check this query this will helps you to get the last entry in the table.

Comment: Hi suresh, please try give all the info about your answer directly in the answer as comments are used for discussions and minor explanations. Also it would be more readable if you could include the code you gave inside a code block.
Thanks and have a nice day!

Comment: I made some changes to the query check now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subselects:

```
INSERT INTO message (from_user_id, to_user_id, text, created_at)
VALUES ((SELECT user.id FROM "user" WHERE username = 'admin'),
        (SELECT user.id FROM "user"
         WHERE created_at = (SELECT max(created_at) FROM "user")
         FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY),
        'selam',
        created_at);
```

String constants use single quotes in SQL.

Comment: but unfortunately it can't get the end user.

Comment: How is the end user identified?

Comment: I want to define the most recently added entry to the table as the person who will receive the message. user_id -

Comment: There is no way to find the latest added row in SQL. You'll have to use a column that registers the creation date, like in my extended answer.

Comment: I want to ask a question. Now I would like to send 2 messages to every new user who registered to the site. The first message already goes automatically with the trigger. but how can I send the 2nd message after 3 minutes? is it possible?

mysql event scheduler I know. but I don't know if it's possible to schedule the trigger.

Comment: No, you cannot do that in the database. But you could display certain messages only when their `created_at` has reached a certain age.

Comment: I don't know if we have to ask a new question about this subject, but can you give us more information?

Comment: Alternatively, create the second message with a `created_at` in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, link to the "user" table twice like this.

```
SELECT from_user.id, to_user.id, "selam", created_at 
FROM user from_user, user to_user 
WHERE from_user.username = "admin"
AND to_user.username = "user_id"
```

or you can try:

```
SELECT from_user.id, to_user.id, "selam", created_at 
FROM user from_user
JOIN user to_user ON to_user.username = "user_id"
WHERE from_user.username = "admin"
```

Both will result in the same output, just different ways to write the same thing.

Is "user_id" and "admin" usernames or Id?
You might need to change:
from_user.username to from_user.id 
and
to_user.username to to_user.id

As your original query suggests usernames, but "user_id" indicates an integer ID value.

Hopefully this helps.